# Как обрезать строку до определенного символа?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в javascript обрезать строку до определенного символа. Т.е., например, есть такая строка `50ml+$100`. И мне нужно, чтобы обрезалось `$100` и наоборот. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Примите ответ, который больше понравился) (галка слева от вопроса)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var a = str.split('+')[0]; // 50ml
var b = str.split('+')[1]; // $100
```

Зачем регулярки?

Comment: А если знаков + много и надо только все после первого знака? Ваше решение не гибкое, а только для вышеприведенного примера.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "50ml+$100";
//Обрезаем конец:
var from = str.length - 4; //4 - длина '$100';
var to = str.length;
$newstr = str.substring(from,to);
//Обрезаем начало:
var from = 0;
var to = 4;
$newstr = str.substring(from,to);

//Это два независимых куска =)
//a)
$strArray = str.split('+'); // разбивает на два куска
//b)
$strMl = str.match(/\d+ml/); // ищет совпадения количества миллилитров
$strDollar = str.match(/\$\d+/); // ищет совпадения количества долларов
```

Comment: а если с помощью регулярных выражений? и обрезать нужно все до и после знака +

Comment: обновил

Answer (score 3):

Если не знаете номер символа то можно воспользовать функцией search.
Т.е. например:

```
str = "50ml+$100";
//Обрезаем конец:
var from = str.search('$100'); 
var to = str.length;
$newstr = str.substring(from,to);
```

Comment: а если с помощью регулярных выражений?
и обрезать нужно все до и после знака +

Comment: ну да... с помощью регулярок то конечно лучше будет... честно говоря не пользовался регулярками на javascript, поэтому наверное так и ответил...

Answer (score 0):

Всех благодарю, спасибо! Cделал так

```
var selectedText = $j('.product-custom-option option:selected').text();
var splArr = selectedText.split(' +');
$j('#sel').text(splArr[0]);
$j('#sel1').text(splArr[1]);
```