# Как удалить символ до "#"

Tags: javascript

Как мне удалить всё что находится до #-якоря, а после якоря ничего не удалять в этом коде - `<a href="тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка-на-элемент">`? Я попробовал так:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');

var href = a.href;
var world = href.substring("39", "100");

console.log(world);
```

```html
<a href="тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка-на-элемент">
```

Но так как у меня алиасы(всё что до #) разные по индексам, так что этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обрезать строку до определенного символа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28910/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: `'тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка-на-элемент'.replace(/^.+?#/, '')`, `'тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка-на-элемент'.split('#')[1]`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var s1 = "тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка-на-элемент"
var s2 = "dadawd#213feg4b5h43r"

function magic(s) {
  return s.substr(s.indexOf("#") + 1, s.length)
}

console.log(magic(s1))
console.log(magic(s2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно проще:

```js
const a =  document.querySelector('a');

console.log(a.hash);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/#foo"></a>
```

Но если нужно рабоать со строкой, тогда возможны, например, такие варианты:

```js
const href = "тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка на элемент";

console.log(href.replace(/.+(?=#)/, ''));
console.log(href.match(/#.+/)[0]);
console.log(href.split(/(?=#)/)[1]);
console.log(href.slice(href.indexOf('#')));
console.log(href.slice(href.search(/#/)));
```